Content Script in Manifest v3 not as fast as v2?
I am working on a Chrome extension, and it's currently published with Manifest v2,
I also have a Manifest v3 version, however there's one small difference in functionality.
Consider the following content script, same for v2 and v3:
var AGScript = `

    var setAgent = function(win)
    {
        try
        {
            Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "userAgentData", {value:undefined});
            Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "platform", {value:undefined});
            Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "vendor", {value:undefined});
            Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "userAgent", {value:"xxx"});
            Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "appVersion", {value:"xxx"});
        } catch(e) {}
    };

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { setAgent(window); });
    document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) { if (event.target.tagName == "IFRAME") setAgent(event.target.contentWindow); });
    setAgent(window);

`;

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.textContent = AGScript;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
script.remove();

And the following v2 manifest section:
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "content-ag.js" ],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ]

Also, a v3 manifest:
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "content-ag.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "world": "MAIN"
   } ]

When testing on the following page: https://browserleaks.com/javascript
the v2 redefines userAgent for both window and iframe.contentWindow,
and yet v3 is only able to do it in window.
I have tried playing with different manifest options, but just can't get it.
Yet, on the following page: https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent
both versions are able to change everything, including iframes.
This leads me to believe it's a timing problem.

Update.
As suggested I have added "match_origin_as_fallback": true, as well as changed the content script to the following:
(() => {

        console.log("here!");

        var setAgent = function(win)
        {
            try
            {
                Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "userAgentData", {value:undefined});
                Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "platform", {value:undefined});
                Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "vendor", {value:undefined});
                Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "userAgent", {value:"xxx"});
                Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "appVersion", {value:"xxx"});
            } catch(e) {}
        };

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { setAgent(window); });
        document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) { if (event.target.tagName == "IFRAME") setAgent(event.target.contentWindow); });
        setAgent(window);

 })()

Unfortunately userAgent is not overridden when tested with https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/
here! is printed in the console. Did I mess up somewhere?
(I was trying in manifest v2, not that it should make any difference)

Update in regards to interceptor for contentWindow:
Very interesting code, it seems to break the site:  https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/ specifically "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigator')":
        function getUAs() {
            const frame = document.createElement("iframe");
            frame.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-same-origin"),
            frame.src = "javascript:false",
            frame.classList.add("hidden"),
            document.body.appendChild(frame);
            const {userAgent: userAgent, appVersion: appVersion} = frame.contentWindow.navigator; \\ BREAKS HERE
            return frame.remove(),
            [navigator.userAgent, _navigator.userAgent, "Mozilla/" + _navigator.appVersion, headerUA, userAgent, "Mozilla/" + appVersion]
        }

When I replace:
const fp = wnd.HTMLIFrameElement.prototype;  with
const fp = wnd.HTMLElement.prototype;
it fixes it, but then the code doesn't override ua as expected.

I could not get IIFE to work as expected, see above.

DOMNodeInserted still seems to work, at least in Opera. However I believe the difference in behavior between v2 and v3 lies somewhere else, appears to be a timing issue.

Looks like a bug in Chrome: it doesn't report the iframe in DOMNodeInserted. Since these mutation events are deprecated the problem isn't likely to be fixed, so soon there will be no way for extension to override the user agent, other than chrome.debugger API which shows a big warning on top of all pages.
Another bug is that match_origin_as_fallback + world:MAIN doesn't run content scripts in sandboxed iframes.
The workaround is to run a second script in the default world with match_origin_as_fallback so it'll run inside such sandboxed iframes and send a message to the MAIN-world script in the parent:
// manifest.json
  "content_scripts": [{
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "content-main.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "world": "MAIN"
  }, {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "content.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "match_origin_as_fallback": true
  }],

// content-main.js
(function setAgent(wnd) {
  try {
    const nav = wnd.navigator;
    const {Object} = wnd;
    Object.defineProperty(nav, 'userAgentData', {value: undefined});
    Object.defineProperty(nav, 'platform', {value: undefined});
    Object.defineProperty(nav, 'vendor', {value: undefined});
    Object.defineProperty(nav, 'userAgent', {value: 'xxx'});
    Object.defineProperty(nav, 'appVersion', {value: 'xxx'});
    const {apply} = wnd.Reflect;
    const fp = wnd.HTMLIFrameElement.prototype;
    const descCW = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(fp, 'contentWindow');
    descCW.get = new wnd.Proxy(descCW.get, {
      __proto__: null,
      apply: (fn, thisArg, args) => setAgent(apply(fn, thisArg, args)),
    });
    Object.defineProperty(fp, 'contentWindow', descCW);
  } catch (e) {}
  addEventListener('setAgent123', e => setAgent(e.relatedTarget));
  return wnd;
})(window);

// content.js
if (window !== parent
&& location.protocol === 'about:'
&& Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(parent.location, 'href').get) {
  parent.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('setAgent123', {relatedTarget: window}));
}


Yes, I guess since overriding the user agent won't be possible soon, and DOMNodeInserted gets completely dropped, there might be no point trying to fix the behavior under a v3 manifest!

My workaround should work in most cases, supposedly.

Yes, thank you, I tested on v3 and it works in most cases! It doesn't seem to pass the 2 aggressive iframe tests on https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/ only.

Yep, it's because of https://crbug.com/40202434. What if you add DOMNodeInserted to this workaround?

Yes with addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', ...) it works, and after replacing DOMNodeInserted with MutationObserver it doesn't again,- aaaagh :)

I've added an interceptor for contentWindow, which is typically used to get values from an iframe.

Very interesting code, it seems to break the code at https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/, see above edit.

I forgot to add return wnd;, see the edit.

The "addEventListener" is also not required anymore.

What a bizarre way of adding script to one’s own document! :)
When you could’ve just...
<script>

function setAgent(win){
try {
 Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "userAgentData", {value:undefined});
 Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "platform", {value:undefined});
 Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "vendor", {value:undefined});
 Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "userAgent", {value:"xxx"});
 Object.defineProperty(win.navigator, "appVersion", {value:"xxx"});

} catch(e) {}}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { setAgent(window); });
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) { if (event.target.tagName == "IFRAME") setAgent(event.target.contentWindow); });
setAgent(window);

</script>

...and saved yourself a ton of typing and even unnecessary delays!
Ah well... I guess some like to play the mysterious! :)
Onto the problem at hand...
Observation 1:
Instead of "DOMNodeInserted" use "DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument".
The former is suitable for fragments while the latter is self-explanatory.
Observation 2:
You're setting the agent up twice on the main window...

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { setAgent(window); });

setAgent(window);


Why is that? Is that because DOMContentLoaded wasn’t working for you by any chance?
Observation 3:
Why were you not using <all_urls> in manifest II when it was possible since 2011? Or thereabouts...

Re: Observation 3 - I believe "<all_urls>" == "http:///", "https:///", "file:///*" considering ftp: support is gone, but in any case it doesn't change much.

Re: Observation 2 - Yes you're right I believe they do exactly the same, and I can't think of any reason why 1. should be left in the code.

Re: Observation 1 - After changing DOMNodeInserted to DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument, the aggressive iframe test fails on https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/

Re: Adding js code directly to a content script,- this fails and does not override userAgent from a Chrome extension on webpages.
